# How to decode the contract function name and parameters from a Polygon transaction?

Tags: transactions, abi, polygon

Using this transaction: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x1b4165c1093936b74803666c75edd720fbd1713b5f77160e3a726299fb04078d

I thought I could simply decode the `Input Data` using https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder/ to figure out the function name and parameters, so I can call that function directly from Nodejs.

However, it's just returning `undefined` :thinking:

```
const inputData = "0x4ae301550000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000034254430000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

const decodedData = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(inputData);
console.log(decodedData);
```

Am I using this package incorrectly? Is there any other way to figure out the contract function name and parameters for this transaction?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are using the method correctly. the problem is, you don't have the ABI. The ABI is the specification of the contract , similar to variable `testABI` shown as example at https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder/
so, because you don't have it (the ABI) you won't be able to decode the input.

You have to provide the abi specification and that is created during compilation of your solidity code when you pass the `--abi` parameter to `solc` executable

Comment: This isn't my contract though. So without the ABI you're saying there's no way to call the contract functions directly? I can't even "guess" what the ABI would contain?

Comment: you can check the "Ethereum Signature Database" (a public knowledge base of functions) and if it is there, you will know its name and arguments

Comment: without ABI you have to disassemble (decompile) the contract to understand what it does and then you can derive the ABI yourself